# Prevent JQuery to continue when catch an Error

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

When document ready i have set

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
        "error": function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if(XMLHttpRequest.status == 403) {
                display_modal( 'Please login to continue.', 'Session in closed.');
                //XMLHttpRequest.abort();
            }
        }
    });
```

to prevent ajax request from unauthenticated users.

but in a specific view, when a POST/GET request is made I have

```
   var posting = $.post(
            post_url, 
            $("#" + form).serialize(),
            function(data) {
                packet = data;
            },
            'json'
    );
    posting.done(function() { 
        form_post_response_function(e, packet); 
    });
    posting.fail(function() {
        var packet = {};
        packet.data = {};
        packet.data.type = "Ajax Post Fail";
        packet.status = -200;
        packet.statusMessage = "ERROR";
        form_post_response_function(e, packet); 
    });
```

I was expecting to `posting.fail(function() {` and `getting.fail(function() {` not be called. But they are, so all the flow goes and it ends with another modal overlaping the 403 message.

How can I avoid this without raw `$.ajax` ? How stop JQuery flow at the error catch?

**FINAL code**

```
posting.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    if(jqXHR.status != 403) {
        var packet = {};
        packet.data = {};
        packet.data.type = "Ajax Post Fail";
        packet.status = -200;
        packet.statusMessage = "ERROR";
        form_post_response_function(e, packet); 
} else {
           // event also can be accessed here
           $(get_target(e)).button('reset');
    }
});
```

and it stop gently. looks good.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not really clear what's the problem

Comment: I believe the local error handlers are always called before the global handler which is where your problem would stem from

Comment: Handlers applied to directly to the response are always raised before global ones. You need to change the logic. Using `$.ajax()` (or any other AJAX shortcut) would make no difference.

Comment: If you get rid of the global ajax error handler then it will do what you have asked.  I think you need to be more clear about your problem.

Comment: The global handler is called just before the $.post, you are right. Couldn't I just get the ajax.status inside fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See que Question for all the details

This is the final code

```
posting.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    if(jqXHR.status != 403) {
        var packet = {};
        packet.data = {};
        packet.data.type = "Ajax Post Fail";
        packet.status = -200;
        packet.statusMessage = "ERROR";
        form_post_response_function(e, packet); 
} else {
           // event also can be accessed here
           $(get_target(e)).button('reset');
    }
});
```

Comment: What is form_post_response_function function doing?

Answer (score 0):

Throw an exception to stop the execution of further code.

For example: `throw "stop execution here";`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw

Comment: Thanks. I did it. The execution really stops. But I get an uncatched exception on the console. Can I like do a try catch surrouding the $.post or something like that? Where I'm supposed to catch it?

Comment: no throws. just added the formal parameter to final and uala! thanks anyway

Comment: @RubenTrancoso That's one of the most annoying internet habits in existence.  It's "voila" - French for Woohoo! :)